# Existence of affine linear function that dominants the convex function

Tags: probability-theory, convex-analysis

I'm trying to understand Jensen's inequality, but I'm stuck understanding a lemma.

> Let $\phi$ be a convex function, meaning $$\forall \lambda \in [0,1]:\lambda \phi(x) + (1-\lambda)\phi(y) \geq \phi(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)$$
> show that:
> $(i)$There is a linear function $l_a$ for any point $a$ s.t $l_a(x) \leq \phi(x)$ and $l_a(a) = f(a)$
> $(ii)$If \phi is strictly convex then $l_a(x) = f(x) \iff x=a$

in Durret's book "Prbability: theory and examples" following solution is suggested:

> By convexity we have
> $$\lim_{h \downarrow 0}\frac{\phi(a)-\phi(a-h)}{h} \leq \lim_{h \downarrow 0}\frac{\phi(a+h)-\phi(a)}{h}$$
> and both limits exist since they are monotone. choosing $\beta$ between two limits and considering $l_a(x) = \beta(x-a)+a$ yields the desired conclusion.

In Durret's proof, even though I can see that both sequences are monotone, but existence of limit requires that they be bounded below(at least for RHS we need to show that it is bounded below otherwise they may both be equal to $-\infty$).
Also assuming existence of limits, I don't know how to conclude $(ii)$ in the lemma.

Comment: Convex functions can be defined on any real vector space. It sounds like, in this case, $\phi$ is a convex function on $\Bbb{R}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry I should've mentioned that.
it seems I can't edit the post.

Comment: A convex function defined on the reals is locally Lipschitz. However, you don't need that here, it follows from the monotonicity properties of $R$ in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Functions_of_one_variable.

Comment: You should edit the information into the body of the question. Press [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4760720/edit) below your question to do so. For boundedness, the left hand side is bounded from above by the right hand side (pick any fixed $h$ on the right, and it will upper-bound the left side for all $h$). The right hand side is similarly bounded below by the left (choosing any fixed $h$). That should resolve the first question.

Comment: Also, it is the convex function that is dominating the affine function.